# Verify database integrity using Django

Tags: django, database

There is a complex app with the back-end powered by Django. It contains many-to-one many-to-many and `https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/`.

Using Django migration for updating database models.

### Problem

A very complex migration for the existing database fails. There Foreign Key constraint related problems similar to:

> ERROR:  insert or update on table "foo" violates foreign key constraint "D286496390ec910156ccc566ec44e73f"
> DETAIL:  Key (bar_id)=(123) is not present in table "bar".

So in other words there is a record which references a non-existing record in the database.

### Question

Is it possible to somehow use Django to iterate over each object in the database and validate it contains no "broken" records (referencing non-existent records)?

Answer (score 0):

## Short Answer

Yes, you can use django shell `./manage.py shell` to iterate your model and check.

---

## Long Anser

```
$ ./manage.py shell
>>> from your_app.models import MyCoolModel
>>> for item in MyCoolModel.objects.all():
...     if item.foreign_field < 0: # do the control here
...         # fix the non valid.
...         ...
```

Comment: Looking for a generic way to iterate over each model (and each model's record) in the database and verify that none of the foreign key constrains are violated (pointing to non existent records).